# Verify size of list of completablefutures

Tags: java, testing, java-8, mockito, completable-future

I have a code which looks similar to

```
public void myMethod(){
    List<CompletableFuture<Void>> futures = new ArrayList<>();                

    //getQuestion, getAnswer, both returns a CompletableFuture<Void>
    futures.add(getQuestion());                
    futures.add(getAnswer());

    // make sure all the futures are executed.
    CompletableFuture.allOf(futures.toArray(new CompletableFuture[futures.size()])).join();

}
```

- Any pointers on how can I like test if the futures array was of size **2** after the execution of **myMethod()***

Comment: You could make the return type int and just return the size of futures collection?

Comment: Unfortunately, I cant, myMethod() is part of an interface, which is void.

Comment: You'll probably need to set a variable somewhere else then from inside the method and then check that variable after the method has completed, depends on how this is called though cause you'll need to make sure the variable doesn't get updated from multiple places concurrently.

Comment: @Plancke, are you recommending keeping the futures list as the class variable?
If yes, I tried doing that, but  still I'm not sure, how can I test that. Also, I feel probably that's not the right way as well..

Comment: I mean that's one way to go yes, could also just set a field in your class to the size. I'd need to see more of your code to really give a good recommendation beyond changing the interface.

Comment: that is exactly what the code is,
earlier, the code looked like.

`public void myMethod(){
    getQuestion();
    getAnswer();
    ...// bunch of other such methods.
}`

I have made all of them completablefutures and would like all of them to execute(with help of join), before we move out of myMethod.

Since, I am adding all of them in a list, I wanted to check if all of them have been added and executed. I think the right way would be to check the size of the list. 

Unless I'm mistaken?

Comment: CompletableFuture#allOf#join ensures all of them are run and completed. If any of the futures fail, the allOf one will fail too. So you might want to do error handling on the individual futures as the master future might miss a stacktrace if both fail. Why do you need to know how many futures were run btw?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no point in testing the size of the array. In Java, arrays never change their size, which also applies to the array returned by `futures.toArray(…)`. If the size of the array was wrong, it implied that the `toArray` implementation of the particular collection already returned an array of the wrong size.

You can make the code more robust by using `futures.toArray(new CompletableFuture[0]))`, letting the `toArray` implementation create an array of the right size instead of passing in a presized array. As explained in [this article](https://shipilev.net/blog/2016/arrays-wisdom-ancients/), it’s actually even faster, contrary to the old myths.

Of course, for a fixed number of futures, there’s no need to translate between collection and array at all. You could use

```
public void myMethod() {
    CompletableFuture<?>[] futures = { getQuestion(), getAnswer() };

    // make sure all the futures are executed.
    CompletableFuture.allOf(futures).join();
}
```

The contract of `CompletableFuture.allOf` is to return a future that will be completed when all futures are completed and `join()` will unconditionally wait for that completion. There is nothing that would need to be checked. If any of the future completed exceptionally, the `join()` method will throw an exception, either a `CompletionException` having the original exception as a cause or a `CancellationException` when the exceptional completion was caused by cancellation.

Answer (score 0):

You could split the method in two:

```
public void myMethod(){
    List<CompletableFuture<Void>> futures = constructFutures();

    // make sure all the futures are executed.
    CompletableFuture
        .allOf(futures.toArray(new CompletableFuture[futures.size()]))
        .join();
}

List<CompletableFuture<Void>> constructFutures() {
    List<CompletableFuture<Void>> futures = new ArrayList<>();                

    //getQuestion, getAnswer, both returns a CompletableFuture<Void>
    futures.add(getQuestion());                
    futures.add(getAnswer());

    return futures;
}
```

And add the test for `constructFutures()`.